# How to extract the decimal value of float in python

Tags: python, floating-point, decimal

I have a program that is a converter for times in minutes and seconds and returns a float value with a decimal, for example:

`6.57312`

I would like to extract the `.57312` part in order to convert it to seconds.

How can I get python to take only the value after the decimal point and put it into a variable that I can then use for the conversion?

Comment: FYI the decimal part of a float is called the *mantissa*

Answer (score 12):

You can do just a simple operation

```
dec = 6.57312 % 1
```

Answer (score 7):

[`math.modf`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.modf) does that. It also has the advantage that you get the whole part in the same operation.

```
import math
f,i = math.modf(6.57312)
# f == .57312, i==6.0
```

Example program:

```
import math
def dec_to_ms(value):
    frac,whole = math.modf(value)
    return "%d:%02d"%(whole, frac*60)

print dec_to_ms(6.57312)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this also

```
num = 6.57312
dec = num - int(num)
```